# how to receive XML in IE8 with mootools

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, mootools, xmlhttprequest

I'm doing a web where I heavily use AJAX requests to
a XML service. In fact, my web is a front-end with almost
no server whatsoever and uses AJAX to communicate with
the back-end.

Everything was going fine (I developed and tested in Ubuntu 9.04
and Firefox 3.0 as a browser).
One day I decided to see how my web did in IE8...
horror!

Nothing was working as it marvelously did in Firefox.
To be more specific, the Request.HTML's were not working.
As I said, my web relied heavily on that, so nothing worked.

I spent a day trying to get something running but I had no luck..
The only conclusion to which I arrived was that the XML was
incorrectly parsed
(I hope I'm in mistake). Let's get to the code:

```
var req = new Request.HTML({
        url: 'service/Catalog.groovy',

        onSuccess: function(responseTree, responseElements) {

            var catz = responseElements.filter('category');
            catz.each(function(cat){
                // cat = $(cat);
                var cat_id = cat.get('id');
                var subcategory = cat.getElement('subcategory');
                alert(cat_id);
                alert(cat.get('html'));
                alert(subcategory.get('html'));
           }
       },
       onFailure: function(){...}

});
```

for example, that piece of code.
In firefox, it worked perfectly. It alerted an ID (for example, 7),
then it showed the contents of the category element, for example:

```
<subcategory id='1'>
      <category_id>7</category_id>
      <code>ACTIO</code>
      <name>Action</name>
</subcategory>
```

and then it showed the contents of some inner element, in this case:

```
<category_id>7</category_id>
<code>ACTIO</code>
<name>Action</name>
```

In IE8, the first alert worked OK (alerted 7)
but the next alert (alert(cat.get('html'));) gave an empty string
and the last threw an Exception... it said something about subcategory
beeing null.

What I concluded with this all is that the elements where parsed
correctly
in Firefox, but in IE8 I only got the tags and the attributes OK,
everything else
was completely wrong (in fact, missing). I mean, the inner content of
all the
elements of the response where gone!

Other fact you could use: this code:

```
alert(cat.get('tag')); resulted in
      Firefox: category
      IE8: /category <-----------(?)
```

hmm what else...
oh yeah... the line you see commented above (`cat = $(cat);`) was
something
I tried to do to fix this. I read in the mootools Docs that IE needed
to explicitly call
the `$` function on elements to get all the Element-magic ... but this
didn't fix anything.

I was so desperate... I even fiddled around with `mootools.js` code

OK, so...
What I want you, dear mootool-pro's is to help me solve this problem,
for I REALLY need the web to function in IE8, and in fact I chose
mootools to forget about compatibility problems...

ps: if something is not clear, please ASK! I'd appreciate any help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue like this sometime ago using jQuery. The problem was that, in IE, the incoming response data needed to be handled by the `Microsoft.XMLDOM` ActiveX object.

The general steps are to:

1. Instantiate the ActiveX object.

   `var oXmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");`
2. Pass it the incoming response data and load it.

   `oXmlDoc.loadXML(sXmlResponseData);`
3. Parse it as needed.

You can check out the full resolution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624723/getting-htmlunknownelement-with-jquery-find-and-an-xml-document/627224#627224).