# Parse XML in Mootools

Tags: javascript, xml, mootools

There doesn't seem to be any useful documentation out there about parsing XML in Mootools. Either it's so stupidly easy nobody could be bothered to mention it, or it's so fiendishly difficult everybody's given up trying. Does anyone have any simple cross browser method for parsing XML with Mootools?

Here's my little XML file data.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<suggestions>
   <suggestion winning="Y">
      <copy><![CDATA[Draw straws to see who wins]]>
      </copy>
      <person><![CDATA[Sue]]>
      </person>
      <location><![CDATA[London]]>
      </location>
   </suggestion>
   <suggestion winning="N">
      <copy><![CDATA[Race your friends round the meeting room]]>
      </copy>
      <person><![CDATA[Jack]]>
      </person>
      <location><![CDATA[Lancaster]]>
      </location>
   </suggestion>
</suggestions>
```

And this is my JS:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){

    var outputHTML = '';

    var req = new Request({
        url: 'data.xml',
        method: 'get',
        onSuccess: function(responseText, responseXML) {                
            if(typeOf(responseXML) != 'document'){
                responseXML = responseXML.documentElement; 
            }
            var suggestions = responseXML.getElements('suggestion');
            suggestions.each(function(item) {
                    outputHTML += '<p>';
                    outputHTML += item.getElement('copy').get('text') + '<br/>';
                    outputHTML += '<b>' + item.getElement('person').get('text') + '</b>: ';
                    outputHTML += item.getElement('location').get('text')  + '<br/>';                   
                    if (item.get('winning') == 'Y') {
                        outputHTML += ' <b>Won!</b>';
                    }
                    outputHTML += '</p>';
            });
            $('output').set('html', outputHTML); 
        }
    }).send();

});
```

I found I had to do the `responseXML = responseXML.documentElement` bit to make it work in Chrome. This JS works OK in Chrome and FF, but IE complains "Object doesn't support this property or method" for line 16, where I'm trying to run getElements('suggestion') on responseXML.

Can any kindly expert restore my faith in the mystical powers of Mootools?

Cheers
Fred

Comment: Maybe you need to use the "Microsoft.XMLDOM" ActiveX object as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601873/how-to-receive-xml-in-ie8-with-mootools

Comment: Thanks ZombieHunter, I noticed that post and also thought that's possibly what I need to do. Meanwhile I'll see if anybody has any other ideas. Seems odd to me that Mootools can't handle this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a rather old question but I recently had the same problem, so I'd like to share my solution.

The `responseXML` variable you receive from `Request` is simply the unaltered XML response from your browser. Under IE (up to version 9), you'll receive an IXMLDOMDocument object. I found that the easiest way to convert this object to a MooTools `Element` tree is the following:

```
function(responseText, responseXML) {
    var doc = responseXML.documentElement;
    if (doc.xml) {
        doc = new Element('div', { html: doc.xml }).getFirst();
    }
    // Now you can use 'doc' like any other MooTools Element
}
```

Alternatively, you can use IE's `DOMParser` which might be more efficient:

```
function(responseText, responseXML) {
    var doc = responseXML.documentElement;
    if (doc.xml) {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var html = parser.parseFromString(doc.xml, 'text/xml');
        doc = document.id(html.documentElement);
    }
    // Now you can use 'doc' like any other MooTools Element
}
```

Comment: Thanks nwellnhof, I'm not able to try this with my original code, but this seems a practical answer to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In MooTools Forge there is a plugin for converting XML to a JavaScript object:

http://mootools.net/forge/p/xml2js_converter

Comment: Thanks Luwe, I'll have a look at that - that may be a neater solution.. Just seems a bit strange that with Mootools I have to convert the XML to work with it.

Comment: Normally you'd need to do the same with JSON strings, but they have that covered in their Core script. XML is a bit more of a problem decoding into a JS Object than JSON is. Do you really have to use XML? Is JSON not a better option in your case?

Comment: I see, thanks Luwe. Yes, unfortunately I have to use XML in this case.