# Mootools Ajax Request with an XML response

Tags: javascript, css, mootools

Hi I am doing a request to an ashx and it returns an XML. I was trying to see how to access to the elements of the XML (it is basically an XmlNode) with this structure hipotetically:

```
<Node>
 <Title>Mootools Ajax Request</Title>
 <question>1<question>
 <response>0</response>
</Node>
```

This is my Ajax request:

```
$$('.linkButton').each(function (el) {
    el.addEvent('click', function (e) {
        e = new Event(e);
        e.stop();
        var data = 'ID=' + el.get('ID');
        spinner= new Spinner(el, { containerPosition: { relativeTo: el, position: 'left', 'class': 'spinner-img' } });
        var myRequest = new Request.HTML({
            method: 'post', url: 'getRequest.ashx',
            onRequest: function () {
                spinner.show(true);
                enableButton(el.get('ID'));
            },
            onSuccess:
                function (responseText, responseXML) {
                    (function () {
                        spinner.hide(true);
                        spinner.destroy();
                        TextOut(el.get('title'));
                    }).delay(5000);
            }
            //Here I want to access to element of my XML... responseXML
        });

        myRequest.send(data);
    })
})
```

I was trying so many ways and says doesnt exist the function or undefined...
Thakns in advance!!!!

EDITED:

I tried with the solution at the post refered but I´ve got this:

```
TypeError: doc is undefined
if (doc.xml) {
```

Edited2:

I finally could resolve it doing this...

responseXML.filter('TagName')[0].get('text');

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse XML in Mootools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107880/parse-xml-in-mootools)

Comment: I did the same on that post and any success that´s why I made a new post... :(

Comment: If you found a solution for this, please post it as an answer. ABout your question, you need to access the response inside the response function since ajax request is async.