# Mootools Response XML get text failed at IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, mootools

I have a problem when I am trying to read an XML return by an ajax response, this only happens at IE8, dont know why? What should I do to parse or to get the text from my XML?
Here is my request and how I get the value of my XML. Would appreciate your response!

```
$$('.linkButton').each(function (el) {
    el.addEvent('click', function (e) {
        e = new Event(e);
        e.stop();
        var data = 'MyData';
        var myRequest = new Request.HTML({
            method: 'post', url: 'MyURL.ashx',
            onRequest: function () {
                //DoSomething
            },
            onSuccess:
                function (responseText, responseXML) {
                    // do something
                    alert(responseXML.filter('NodeName')[0].get('text')
            }
        });

        myRequest.send(data);
    })
})

XML:

<Node>
 <NodeName>Here is the name</NodeName>
 <NodeValue>Here is the Value</NodeValue>
</Node>
```

the error is :

```
{exception} Unable to get property 'get' of undefined or null reference
```

Comment: Are there any errors ?

Comment: At IE it just dont show the alert..but at ie9, ie10, mozilla, chrome, safari show the alert...but ie8 doenst work...

Comment: Is responseXML an array ?

Comment: array.filter() isn't supported in IE < 9

Comment: and so , this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153470/why-wont-filter-work-in-interent-explorer-8

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse XML in Mootools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107880/parse-xml-in-mootools)